# Mongodb Aggregation returning nothing when trying to do $lookup and $unwind

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, rest, express

I am trying to get messages based on a `chatroomId` and returning all the messages in that chatroom as well as add all the data about the user from the `userId`. I tried the following but it is returning an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
chatMessageSchema.statics.getConversationByRoomId = async function (
  chatRoomId,
  options = {}
) {
  try {
    return this.aggregate([
      { $match: { chatRoomId } },
      { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },

      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "User",
          localField: "userId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user",
        },
      },
      { $unwind: "$user" },

      { $skip: options.page * options.limit },
      { $limit: options.limit },
      { $sort: { createdAt: 1 } },
    ]);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`{ $match: { chatRoomId } }` => `{ $match: { _id:chatRoomId } }`

```
db.chatMessages.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: 1 }
  },
  {
    $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "User",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user"
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $sort: { createdAt: 1 }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gFGrQ7Odtvc)

Comment: I tried this, still not working.
```js
      { $match: { _id: chatRoomId } },
      { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "User",
          localField: "userId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user",
        },
      },
      { $unwind: "$user" },
      { $skip: options.page * options.limit },
      { $limit: options.limit },
      { $sort: { createdAt: 1 } },
```

Comment: Also I tried with the `id:` and it made it worse. Because when i remove the lookup and rewind it works but when i add the `id:` it stops working (returning empty array).

Comment: @ssaqan In my [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gFGrQ7Odtvc) it worked. You had better check every level of aggregation and all of your input parameter.